# Saving already Opened File in JFileChooser Java?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How to save a file if it is already opened without opening the `FileChooser dialog` like notepad ?
It took me so much time to figure out. I've searched the net but could not find something could help me here.

Thanks in Advance

My issue is in the code below.  The new edit is not saved. I opened the same file and nothing was saved (not updated I mean)

```
 fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new
 FileWriter(openFile.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
```

```
private class FileAction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //JOptionDialog
        JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
        openFile.setFileFilter(new txtFilter());
        if(e.getSource() == open ){

            int openOption = openFile.showOpenDialog(frame);

                    textArea.setText(""); //clearing the Text_AREA before opening the new file

                try{
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(openFile.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    while(scan.hasNext())
                        textArea.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n");

                }catch(Exception ex){
                    //ShowDialogBox dialogBox = new ShowDialogBox();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Please choose .txt File only");
                }
            }
        } else if( e.getSource() == save){  //SAVE_BUTTON

            try{
                BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(openFile.getSelectedFile().getPath())); //(This does not save at all I opened the file again and still as it was before editing)
                fileWriter.write(textArea.getText());
                fileWriter.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){

            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Did you try saving the handle to the opened file and then create the file writer like this: `new FileWriter(openedFile))`?

Comment: i'm sorry it's not error, the file is not being saved. when I open it again I don't see the text I added before saving. Let me edit the comment so it does not make a confusion for you guys.

Comment: You have an empty catch block, and should rarely ever have this as you are then flying blind. At least print out the stack trace to be sure that you're not missing an exception.

Comment: @Thomas I tried doing that and it says `Cannot Find Variable openedFile`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes, I assume he's getting a NPE since `openFile` is a newly created `JFileChooser` and nothing has been selected yet.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added a print out.  Nothing is printing when clicking on the `save` button, so it's okay.

Comment: @Thomas where should I create it? and what should I put inside it?

Comment: @AlexDunham: If you've changed your code, you should show the latest  update because we have no idea what specific changes you've made. Also, you should close your Scanner after you're done with it -- after reading in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, I assume you get a `NullPointerException` since when `save` (it is a button, right?) is pressed, the action creates a new `JFileChooser` instance which hasn't a selected file yet.

So you should store the selected file when it is opened in an instance variable (use `openFile.getSelectedFile()` in the `open` branch) and pass that file handle to the `FileWriter` that is created in the `save` branch.

If you're reusing the same instance of `FileAction` you could put the reference there, otherwise you could put it somewhere else (maybe some container object that is passed to the action) where multiple instances of `FileAction` have access to.

Just a word in advance: *do resist* the temptation to use a static variable, that's not an appropriate usage of statics.

Comment: I really Appreciate your help. My Issue here is how to pass the handler since it's inside the try and catch block.

Comment: @AlexDunham this has nothing to do with the try-catch block. After opening a file using the file chooser you can get the handle using `openFile.getSelectedFile()`. Store that in a way that the invocation of the save action has access to that handle. As I said, if you're using the same instance of the action you could use an instance variable, for simplicity.

Comment: I'm using the same Action, but my problem is silly. The File will be selected inside the IF-Statment(open branch), so If I created an Instance Variable of the at the beginning , the ` openFile.getSelectedFile();` nothing is selected. I think you got it. I don't know how to get that selectedFile  from the `open` branch statement and pass it to the `save` branch.   I'm really giving up since I've been trying for quite time to do this.

Comment: @AlexDunham you have to call `getSelectedFile()` after `int openOption = openFile.showOpenDialog(frame);` and of course it will only work if the file was actually opened (check the value of `openOption`). Then write it to an instance variable in the action. Have a look at the documentation of `JFileChooser` for more information.

Comment: I already did what you said. But still I don't know how to write it in an Instance variable in the action.  Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not related to your problem but you should NOT be using fileWriter.write(...).

Instead you should be using `textArea.write(...)`. See [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more information.

Comment: happy new year from Old Continent, btw +1